# x86 assembly, ROR rotation, count from register or memory

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am writing code using nasm in x86 assembly. I would like to be able to do this(in EAX is number of rotations, or under [EBP + 12]):

```
ror ESI, EAX ;count- register
ror ESI, DWORD [EBP + 12] ;count- memory
```

but it is impossible. ror only accept immediate constants like

```
ror ESI, 4  ; four right rotations
```

I don't like to do loop:

```
loop:  
ror ESI, 1
sub EAX, 1
cmp EAX, 0
jg loop
```

Probably there is a better solution of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that ROR only works with CL register, for example:

```
ror ESI, CL
```

Comment: Intel and AMD both document `CL` to be a valid parameter to `ROR`  Guess nobody reads documentation anymore.